# Job run breaking with the same error message

Tags: sql, azure, jobs

Invoke-ProcessASDatabase : Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.. The exception was raised by the IDataReader interface. Please review the error message and provider documentation for further information and corrective action. Technical Details: RootActivityId: d4d3b43a-004b-4c6e-b73e-cd2829ff3311 Date (UTC): 4/14/2022 12:00:24 PM The database operation was cancelled because of an earlier failure. '. At line:2 char:1 + Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -DatabaseName "ProjectsBI" -Server "asazure: ... +

Comment: I agree. It looks like your job threw an error. Can you provide more information so we can help troubleshoot?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.